# how to fit background video to all screen sizes

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am designing a website with video background. When page load, video to fit in all screens. Then we scroll, rest of the website content to be show. On video content i  want to put header and some content. I need exactly like https://fishermenlabs.com/. please help me. please check my code below. its not working. Please help me.

```
   <div class="vdbg">   
    <div class="video">  
      <video autoplay muted loop id="myVideo">
       <source src="images/cnk.mov" type="video/mp4">
      </video>
    </div> 
   </div>
```

Please check my css code

```
 .vdbg {
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 100%; 
    background-color: #000;
    }
   #myVideo {
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    min-width: 100%; 
    min-height: 100%;
    opacity: 0.5;
    background-color: #000;
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to have a container div, which fits to the screen, and then add a class to the video which will resize it to width or height.

CSS:

```
.container {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
position: absolute;
padding:0;
margin:0;
left: 0px;
top: 0px;
z-index: -1000;
overflow:hidden;
}

.videoPlayer {
    min-height: 100%;
    //min-width:100%; - if fit to width
position:absolute;
bottom:0;
left:0;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="container"><video class="videoPlayer">Code goes here</video></div>
```

Or Read this..
Source: [WesBOS](https://wesbos.com/css-object-fit/)

Comment: After container div i want to put website content. I am trying but content is showing above the video container div.

Comment: Please check this example>>  [link](https://startbootstrap.com/snippets/video-header/)

Comment: Than you. But client wants to display video full screen or fit to all screen sizes when website load.

Comment: I have done with background image in previous but i can not do with video. Please help me

Answer (score 1):

## Background Video

The main idea of the following demo is that you have the video tag separate from the rest of the layout and give it `z-index:-1`. For the rest of the layout, arrange it however you want but make sure that each sibling of the video tag has `background:none`.

---

### Demo

```css
html {
  font: 400 16px/1.5 Verdana;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  padding: 0 2em 0 0;
}

body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  background: none;
  padding: 0 2em 0 0;
}

#vid {
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  min-width: 100vw;
  min-height: 100vh;
  opacity: 0.5;
  background-color: #000;
  z-index: -1;
}

main {
  position: relative;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background: none;
  padding: 0 2em 0 0;
}

header {
  position: absolute;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  text-align: center;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 5vw;
  line-height: 1.1;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

aside {
  margin: 0 0 0 70vw;
  width: 25vw;
}

summary {
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
}

address {
  font-size: 1em;
}
```

```html
<video autoplay muted loop id="vid">
       <source src="https://storage04.dropshots.com/photos6000/photos/1381926/20170326/005609.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
<main>
  <aside>
    <details>
      <summary>Contact</summary>
      <address>
        400 Monte Clair St.<br>
        New York, NY 10001<br>
        bytemy@ss.com
      </address>
    </details>
  </aside>
  <header>
    <h1>Main Title That is Long <br>Enough to Wrap Around</h1>
  </header>
</main>
```